# Creating a cron job with Ansible (ERROR! 'cron' is not a valid attribute for a Play)

Tags: ansible, linux

I am relatively inexperienced when it comes to Ansible however I have previously created playbooks which will create a cron job successfully. For the life of me I cannot work out what is wrong with my .yml file.

I am receiving the below error when attempting to run my playbook locally with:

```
ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local crond.yml


ERROR! 'cron' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to have been in 
'/etc/ansible/cds/roles/backups/tasks/crond.yml': line 3, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- cron:
  ^ here
```

I have seen similar questions asked on SE/Ansible forums but to no avail. Any help/guidance would be much appreciated.

Here is my crond.yml file:

```
- cron:
    user: "root"
    minute: "30"
    hour: "02"
    job: '{{/usr/bin/rsync -avhz -e "ssh" --rsync-path="sudo rsync" -H --delete --numeric-ids <ipaddress>:"/data/rsnapshot-backups/<ipaddress>" /data/rsnapshot-backup}}'
    state: present
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by adding my crond.yml task to the global playbook and now call it via tags (ansible-playbook -vvv -i "localhost," -c local site.yml --tags backups).

I added the cron_file section to define the location of the cron job as /etc/cron.d/rsync.cron rather than the root users crontab. I then added state: present to ensure that the cronjob exists on the server and doesn't delete other entries in the file.

I also updated the job section of the task to remove the '{{ }}' and replace with double quotes surrounding the command as well as '\'s around any double quoted strings like below:

```
- cron:
    name: "Copy all rsnapshot backups from <hostname>"
    minute: "30"
    hour: "02"
    job: "/usr/bin/rsync -avhz -e \"ssh\" --rsync-path=\"sudo rsync\" -H --delete --numeric-ids <ipaddress>:\"/data/rsnapshot-backups/<ipaddress>\" /data/rsnapshot-backup"
    user: root
    cron_file: rsync.cron
    state: present
```

Answer (score 1):

`crond.yml` in your example is not a playbook. It is a tasks file (list of tasks), while playbook is a list of plays.

A play must have `hosts` directive at minimum. Please see http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_intro.html#hosts-and-users

This is a playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - cron:
        user: "root"
        minute: "30"
        hour: "02"
        job: '/usr/bin/rsync -avhz -e "ssh" --rsync-path="sudo rsync" -H --delete --numeric-ids <ipaddress>:"/data/rsnapshot-backups/<ipaddress>" /data/rsnapshot-backup'
        state: present
```

Comment: I have tried using this layout too, I get a syntax error when attempting to run with the same command. My company are using an overarching site.yml, when I run said playbook with --tags backups (relative tag to the crond.yml) it runs, but still fails.

Comment: Yes, syntax error, because you have messed `{{...}}` in job definition. I removed it with my edit.

Comment: No, I need the {{...}} to retain the double quotes around the single quotes.